# Add a label to the editor?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-editor

I'm working on a custom post type. I have the editor enabled but the content that will go in that box is secondary and it isn't clear what should be typed there so I want to add a label for the editor. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hacking around, this is the solution I came up with:

At the top of `functions.php` I have the following line:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'add_title_to_editor');
```

Just thrown in the middle of `functions.php` I have the following function:

```
function add_title_to_editor() {
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'my_custom_post_type') : ?>
        <script> jQuery('<h3>Optional Additional Information</h3>').insertBefore('#postdivrich'); </script>
    <? endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently used this in one of the projects, so here you go

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'wp692_edit_form_after_title' );

function wp692_edit_form_after_title() {
echo '<h2>This is My Label!</h2>';
}
```

Comment: This is a really good option normally. I assume it won't work for me, though, because I already have a function that moves the editor below some other custom fields... ;)